# Simplest method for positioning Tikz shape over image in relative coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf, overlays, coordinates

What concise recipee is there to overlay objects on top of images, using relative coordinates (such as fraction of image width/height)?

For example trying to draw a red rectangle to highlight a specific region of [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdGhE.png):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdGhE.png]

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[inner sep=0, anchor=south west] (img) at (0,0) {
    \includegraphics[keepaspectratio,height=.9\textheight,width=\linewidth]{refgrid_crop}%
};
    \begin{scope}[x={(img.south west)},y={(img.south west)},local bounding box=img]
    \draw[thick, rounded corners, color=red!80!black, anchor=south west] (0.5, 0.3)
        rectangle (0.75, 0.5);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The above code using `scope` does not display at all a rectangle at the wanted fractions `0.5, 0.3`.  Also, I don't understand why, but a rectangle only appears in the lower right region when I set the scope parameters `x` and `y` to `{(img.south east)}`, while expected this parameter to indicate the origin of the coordinate system...

How to switch the *units to image fraction* and *origin to south-west* ?

Comment: `x=1mm, y=1in` is a way to rescale the x-axis and y-axis, not a way to shift things. Shifting is done by `shift={(x, y)}`.

Comment: [A very interesting thread about this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz), in which you can leran that a specific package, called `callouts` may help you out (but other solutions presented are very nice too).

Comment: As you can see from the question linked above, you need `\begin{scope}[x={(img.south east)},y={(img.north west)}]`, not what you currently have.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. thanks, indeed your x,y values work! I probably assumed an incorrect meaning for those x,y parameters, will need to find it in the doc.

Comment: As mentioned above, the `x` and `y` parameters rescale the axes, specifically they define the unit vectors. You've placed the image with the bottom left corner at `(0,0)`, so if you set `x=(img.south east)`, the x unit vector points from bottom left to the bottom right corner of the image. Similarly, with `y=(img.north west)`,  the y unit  vector goes from the bottom left to the top left of the image.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. this is definitely the simplest way (no extra package/library, simple syntax), if you put these comments into an answer I will accept it.

Comment: It's really a duplicate of the previously mentioned question, I think ..

Comment: This mentioned question does not ask specifically for _relative_ coordinates, but it might be implied anyway. So I agree, since the accepted answer is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Easier to show than explain.  The calc tikzlibrary can locate fractional distance between two points.  The following locates (0.5,0.3) relative to the (img) node.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[inner sep=0] (img) {\includegraphics{example-image}};
\coordinate (A) at ($(img.west)!0.5!(img.east)$);% x location
\coordinate (B) at ($(img.south)!0.3!(img.north)$);% y location
\node[red,draw] at (A|-B) {here};
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]